# Can't find the cause of an unhandled exception

Tags: c++, parsing, exception, iostream

I am writing a parser for .obj files, and an unhandled exception  is being thrown somewhere within the for loop for this code block, and I am unable to find it. The visual studio error message is saying that it's at the ntdll.dll. The code then breaks in the ostream file. When I use breakpoints, the program doesn't crash before quite a few iterations.

```
//Intitialising index array for that part and returning to the start of the 
vertex defining period
//iCount is the number of indices that are being read in
//Position is the saved position within the .txt file that has been reached
data[k].indices = new triangle[iCount];
data[k].noIndices = iCount;
data[k].verTex = new point3D[iCount];

int a,b,c,d,e,f;

int check = 0;
inFile.seekg(position - 1);

cout << "Icount" << iCount << endl;

//Getting index data
for(int j = 0; j < iCount; j++)
{
    char buff[40];
    inFile.getline(buff, 40);
    int matched = sscanf(buff, "f %d/%d %d/%d %d/%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);

    //Zero align the indices and store the data
    data[k].verTex[j].x = b - 1;
    data[k].verTex[j].y = d - 1;
    data[k].verTex[j].z = f - 1;

    //Zero align the indices and store the data
    data[k].indices[j].a = a - 1;
    data[k].indices[j].b = c - 1;
    data[k].indices[j].c = e - 1;
}
```

EDIT: When this code block is added in, *fail* is written to the console until the heap corrupts. This is because sscanf() returns -1 after the first iteration if being run without breakpoints

```
if(matched != 6)
{
    cout << "fail";
}
```

Comment: Your debugger probably has an option to stop when an exception is about to be thrown. Try using it without breakpoints (or just a breakpoint when you are about to enter the `for` loop) and see what happens. Specifically, notice the values for all variables when the exception is about to be thrown.

Comment: You might think about using an existing .obj parser. There are many; also, a parser library such as boost spirit might be a better idea than implementing a parser all by yourself. Finally, look [here](http://weblog.benjaminsommer.com/blog/2012/02/12/a-tiny-wavefront-object-loader-part1)

Comment: You should probably post a more complete example, we have no idea what `iCount` or `position` are for example.

Comment: What is controlling `k` and the outer loop around this code?

Comment: This is the last section of code within a while loop which terminates at the end of the file; there is a k++; operator just after this.

Comment: When your program crashes with an unhandled exception, follow the "Call stack" to find the line in your code that leads to the exception being thrown. I also agree with @Wilbert. Boost spirit is extremely efficient (fast) and surprisingly easy, if you get used to the syntax. I wrote an ANSI SQL parser that populates a custom struct within 1-2 days using Spirit qi and Lexer while using it for the first time.

Comment: This is for a university assignment, and it has to be in C++ and standard libraries, so for my particular situation, it's not ideal @Wilbert And call stack has missing frames, and the sections of code that it highlights are either from a library or just calls to the section that I know is broken.

Comment: @Yann4 missing frames are important, if you suspect that it's the shared library you're using that's causing problems. 99% of the times it's your code. Using Call Stack you can see the last line of your code that was executed before jumping to the external code, where the exception was thrown.

Comment: Just a reaction: in c++ you should not use C-arrays like `indices = new triangle[iCount];` but rather std::vectors<> (most of the time).

Comment: The code reacts differently when I go through it by breakpoints than if I just let it run i.e it works with breakpoints, but sscanf() returns -1 without them.